# RExcel How to execute a R code

Tags: r, excel, rexcel, vba

I'm trying to execute a R code using Excel with the Rexcel tool.

I´ve created a button and an associate macro that executes the following code:

```
Sub button()
    RInterface.StartRServer
    RInterface.RunRFile "C:/Users/fran21/Downloads/R_NYSE_Hadoop/predicciones.R"
    RInterface.GetArray "array", Range("A24")
    RInterface.StopRServer    
End Sub
```

I use RunRFile to execute my R code and GetArray to try to show a variable of my R code. The execution doesn't throw errors but I can´t see the results!

Comment: It doesn't look like you tried to print them.

Comment: I don´t know how to print the results. I´m trying it with "array" but it does´t work.

Comment: he tried to print into A24, thats what GetArray does.

Comment: did my answer help? please vote up/accept if so, or let me know if there's a problem if not.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing predicciones.R its difficult to say what the problem is, but try this:

```
Sub button()
    RInterface.StartRServer
```

This should be done in the sub auto_open or otherwise separately. You don't want R to be started every time you run this kind of macro.

```
    RInterface.rrun "source('C:/Users/fran21/Downloads/R_NYSE_Hadoop/predicciones.R')"
    RInterface.rrun "print('array')"
```

printing just to check, this isn't necessary

```
    Range("A24") = RInterface.GetRExpressionValueToVBA("array")
```

Just for a speed improvement. If it doesn't work then try getarray again. If you're working with large matricies and you want more robust code that does work more quickly, I wrote a large function I can post here

```
    'RInterface.StopRServer
```

I wouldn't do this unless you're not going to run any R code again for the rest of the excel session

```
End Sub
```